# Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' in FLUTTER

Tags: json, flutter, listview, widget

This error comes when i tried to wrap the json object in Text widget,the code is as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../drawer.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  var data;
  // Used to initialize something before starting of the screen
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchdata();
  }

  
  fetchdata() async {
    var res = await http.get(url);
    // print(res.body);

    // json parsing
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(data);

    //To tell the UI that we got the data
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Scaffold has prebuild some widget themes
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
      ),

      // Container is similiar to <Div>
      body: data != null
          
          ? ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data[index]["title"]),
              );
            })
```

As you can see ,I'm getting a HTTP response and converting it in to a json object and trying to display the title object in Listview on demand.Even though I wrapped inside the Text widget it show error as,

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Please fix this error,THanks in advance~.Im new to flutter

Comment: What are you returning instead of ListView in your ternary condition if `data == null`?

Comment: Recommend that you use FutureBuilder to init your future and show data when future is finished

Comment: Hi @JRamos29,if data == null,just using a indeterminate circularprogressindiactor widget only

Comment: Hi @OmerGamliel,sorry im new to this flutter,can you please update my above code and explain if you don't mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In check `data != null` and  return `CircularProgressIndicator()` when data is `null` 
code snippet

```
body: data != null
            ? ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data[index]["title"]),
                );
              })
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
```

working demo

[image]
full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  var data;
  // Used to initialize something before starting of the screen
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchdata();
  }

  fetchdata() async {
    var res = await http.get(url);
    // print(res.body);

    // json parsing
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(data);

    //To tell the UI that we got the data
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Scaffold has prebuild some widget themes
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My App"),
        ),
        body: data != null
            ? ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data[index]["title"]),
                );
              })
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really wonder, how is your code working perfectly(demo) without `itemCount` for `ListView.builder()`..?

Comment: Hi @srikanth7785, i think itemcount is optional, i used index na,its more than enough

Comment: Hey @chun,Thanks a lot you saved me,even though my code and yours are the same,I missed that         visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
 in my main.dart

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its the right answer,its my guess only,By seeing the above answers I thought that I missed one thing in the main.dart page,that is ,

```dart
themeData(       
 visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
)
```

Happy fluttering!

Answer (score 0):

In your title, your data should be inside quotes (`""`),
so instead of:

```
title: Text(data[index]["title"]),
```

Provide it like this:

```
title: Text("${data[index]["title"]}"),
```